# Safari doesn't display image [React]

Tags: reactjs, image, safari

In my react app, I have an About page that is supposed to display an image. Here's my code for that:

```html
pages/About.jsx

        <div className={styles.aboutImg}>
          <img src="../public/bg.png" />
        </div>
```

The image `bg.png` is stored in the `public` directory. On chrome, the image appears perfectly fine, but on Safari, it looks like this:

[image]

However, not all images look broken like this, as a background image specified with `background-image: url("myimage.png")` is displayed fine, so it's really strange why this image tag won't display. I am positive the image src is correct, as it works on Chrome, but Safari is what is causing this issue. Any idea on how to fix this, so that the image is displayed properly on all browsers?